# Change relative location for PathBuf

Tags: rust, path

I have a few `PathBuf`s in my Rust application:

```rs
let mut dog_path = PathBuf::from("./animals/dog.png");
let mut cow_path = PathBuf::from("./animals/bovine/cow.jpg");
```

How could I change these `PathBuf`s so that they're being referred to from the `./animals` directory?

```rs
// an operation on dog_path
// same operation on cow_path

assert_eq!(PathBuf::from("./dog.png"), dog_path);
assert_eq!(PathBuf::from("./bovine/cow.jpg"), cow_path);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove `./animals/` from the front of `dog_path`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes.

Comment: Do you want to get last segment of `PathBuf`, or a general solution to transform a `PathBuf` to show path from another directory?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze the second option, PathBuf does come with a .pop() method but that isn't what I'm lookin for -- I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix):

```rust
let dog_path = PathBuf::from("./animals/dog.png");
let cow_path = PathBuf::from("./animals/bovine/cow.jpg");

let dog_path_rel = dog_path.strip_prefix("./animals").unwrap();
let cow_path_rel = cow_path.strip_prefix("./animals").unwrap();
assert_eq!(Path::new("dog.png"), dog_path_rel);
assert_eq!(Path::new("bovine/cow.jpg"), cow_path_rel);
```

But that won't include the leading `./`. If that's important to you, you can add it manually:

```rust
let dog_path_prefixed = Path::new("./").join(dog_path_rel);
let cow_path_prefixed = Path::new("./").join(cow_path_rel);
assert_eq!(PathBuf::from("./dog.png"), dog_path_prefixed);
assert_eq!(PathBuf::from("./bovine/cow.jpg"), cow_path_prefixed);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef93d199ba4d2e7ebaf73fffd36146d9)

Note that `strip_prefix` returns a `Result`, meaning it could fail if the path doesn't begin with the given prefix. You may want to handle this case instead of `unwrap`ing the result (causing your program to exit with a panic), or you may want to use `.expect("your message here")` instead to provide a meaningful error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general solution you could look at [relative-path](https://crates.io/crates/relative-path) crate. It looks like it provide the functionality you want.

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;

use relative_path::RelativePath;

fn main() {
    let dog_path = PathBuf::from("./animals/dog.png");
    let cow_path = PathBuf::from("./animals/bovine/cow.jpg");

    let dog_path = RelativePath::from_path(&dog_path).unwrap();
    let cow_path = RelativePath::from_path(&cow_path).unwrap();
    let animals_dir = RelativePath::new("./animals");

    let dog_path = animals_dir.relative(&dog_path).to_path(".");
    let cow_path = animals_dir.relative(&cow_path).to_path(".");

    assert_eq!(PathBuf::from("./dog.png"), dog_path);
    assert_eq!(PathBuf::from("./bovine/cow.jpg"), cow_path);
}
```

This is a quick draft, but it shows how to do in a generic way what you are trying to accomplish. I think it could be further optimized, but I literally found this crate 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I don't think this really fits their use case. This is more meant for storing relative paths in a platform agnostic manner.

Comment: @PitaJ It turns out it does.

Comment: I see it supports that use case, but I don't really see the point of using an external crate when a perfectly suitable function exists in the standard library.

Comment: @PitaJ I believe that OP wants a *general* solution. One where relative location isn't known in advance.

Comment: What about `split_prefix` is not a general solution? You can pass any Path-like value to it.

Comment: What if you cannot just strip prefix? If you have a file "./a/b/c" and a folder "./a/d" then file's path relative to the folder is "../b/c".